# Problem with calculating dates in MS Access (DateDiff)

Tags: ms-access

I want to calculate day difference between two dates but none of my methods worked.

I tried using DateDiff and this was my function:

DateDiff("d";[Date1];20/11/2022)

But it was giving me some really big numbers as the results (it showed that difference between 06.2020 and 11.2022 is over 40000 days).

I also tried dates substraction. It worked with Date() but didn't work with a specific date.

Date() - [Date1] -> gives number of days

01/01/2023 - [Date1] -> goes back in time and the result is e.g. 01.01.1779

Comment: Summary of the duplicate:  use octothorpes to delimit the date and use either mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd, so `DateDiff("d";[Date1];#11/20/2022#)`.